# JavaScript. tengo dos errores, uno para sacar el total. y otro para simular un clic en un botón, cuando se modifique un input (cantidad)

Tags: javascript

Saludos a toda la comunidad, les pido ayuda por favor en estos dos errores. Las tablas serán dinámicas, es para un sistema de ventas.

1. Para sacar el total, presionado el los botones actualizar.
2. Por ultimo, simular el clic al botón actualizar, cuando se modifique la cantidad, por que luego el botón actualizar se pondrá como hidden (oculto).

```js
// funcion para vender por cantidad (mayor a 12 por docena).
// funciona gracias a esta comunidad. 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("formulario").addEventListener('submit', validarFormulario); 
});
function validarFormulario(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    let cant_vm = parseFloat( document.getElementById("cant_vm").value );
    let cant_actual = document.getElementsByClassName("cant_actual");

    for(var i = 0; i < cant_actual.length; i++) {
      if (parseFloat(cant_actual[i].value) < cant_vm) {
         alert("Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a "+ cant_vm)
         cant_actual[i].focus()
         return 0; 
      }
    }
    this.submit(); 
}

// funcion incompleta, no saca el total.
// las tablas seran dinamicas, como la funcion (validarFormulario)
function multi() {
    let prec = document.getElementsByClassName("prec");
    let cant = parseFloat( document.getElementById("cant").value );
    var resul = document.getElementById("resul").value = prec*cant;
    alert("se saco el total");
}

// funcion incompleta, que simule clic en el boton actualizar.
// posterior el boton actualizar se pondra como hidden (oculto).
function btn_auto_actu() {
    alert("yes se autopresiono el boton actualizar");
}
```

```html
<form action="vender.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Producto</td>
    <td>Precio</td>
    <td>Cantidad</td>
    <td>Act. Cantidad</td>
    <td>Total</td>
</tr>
<tbody>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="TECLADO"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="" value="50" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="cant" value="1" class="cant_actual"
        onchange="clic_actu()"></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="" value="Actualizar" onClick="multi()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="resul" value="50"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="MOUSE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="" value="30" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="cant" value="1" class="cant_actual"
        onchange="clic_actu()"></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="" value="Actualizar" onClick="multi()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="resul" value="30"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="PARLANTE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="" value="80" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="cant" value="1" class="cant_actual"
         onchange="clic_actu()"></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="" value="Actualizar" onClick="multi()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="resul" value="80"></td>
    </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
 <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>
<br>
<label>Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a </label>
<input type="text" value="12" id="cant_vm">
```

Saludos a toda la comunidad, les pido ayuda por favor en estos dos errores. Las tablas serán dinámicas, es para un sistema de ventas.

1. Para sacar el total, presionado el los botones actualizar.
2. Por ultimo, simular el clic al botón actualizar, cuando se modifique la cantidad, por que luego el botón actualizar se pondrá como hidden (oculto).

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Hola, lo primero es que tu pregunta no se entiende bien, también es importante que los cálculos de precios deben hacerse en el backend (php) mas no en el frontend (JavaScript), lo cual sirve para dar seguridad a los datos, entonces si en el php tienes un ciclo para imprimir los registros de venta, ahí mismo en una variable acumulativa los vas sumando para después mostrarlos

Comment: saludos Alanfcnm, el primer error.
no saca el total presionado el botón actualizar (sacar el total), posterior mente cuando ya saque el total, los botones actualizar se los va a poner como hidden (oculto), con otra función onchange en el input cantidad quiero ejecutar la simulación del clic en el botón actualizar que ya va estar oculto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas un botón actualizar, debes ocupar el evento oninput , algo como esto

```
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name=""  value="TECLADO"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="a"  value="50"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="b"  value="1" class="cant_actual" oninput="total.value=parseInt(a.value) * parseInt(b.value)"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total" value="30"></td>
    </tr>
```

Cuando generes la tabla dinámicamente deber ir colocando los Id's y los name's según corresponda.

Comment: Yussef,  gracias funciono para una fila, pero para dos o mas filas, ya no me garra los id="" la taba será dinámica

Comment: Arnol, eso es lo que te señalaba al final de mi respuesta. Como iras generando cada fila de la tabla, puedes ir agregando los id según corresponda, por ejemplo agregando un sufijo, cant1, cant2, cant3..etc. De todas manera me alegro que hayas encontrando la solución a tu problema

Answer (score -1):

Encontré la solución, a mi mismo problema, qui les comparto el código, por si alquilen lo necesita, mi error era sacar los datos de los input mediante los id, se tenia que hacer mediante clases, los id solo pueden ser tomados una vez, por eso solo sacaba el total de la primera fila, en cambio con clases puedo tomar varios datos de barios input

```js
// funcion para vender por cantidad (mayor a 12 por docena).
// funciona gracias a esta comunidad. 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("formulario").addEventListener('submit', validarFormulario); 
});
function validarFormulario(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    let cant_vm = parseFloat( document.getElementById("cant_vm").value );
    let cant_actual = document.getElementsByClassName("cant_actual");

    for(var i = 0; i < cant_actual.length; i++) {
      if (parseFloat(cant_actual[i].value) < cant_vm) {
         alert("Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a "+ cant_vm)
         cant_actual[i].focus()
         return 0; 
      }
    }
    this.submit(); 
}

// despues de modificar la cantidad. onchange
// llamanos la funcion sacartotal
function actualizar_total() {
  sacartotal();
}

// solo funciona con la primera fila
// sera una tabla dinaminca.
function sacartotal() {
    var cant = document.querySelectorAll('.cant');
    var prec = document.querySelectorAll('.prec');
    var subtotals = document.querySelectorAll('.resul');

    for(var i = 0; i < cant.length; i++){ 
      subtotals[i].value = cant[i].value * prec[i].value;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="echo.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
<table>
<tr>
        <td>Producto</td>
        <td>Precio</td>
        <td>Cantidad</td>
    <!-- <td>Act. Cant.</td> -->
        <td>Total</td>
</tr>
 <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="TECLADO"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="50" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" required class="cant_actual cant" 
        onchange="actualizar_total()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" class="resul"></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="MOUSE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="30" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" required class="cant_actual cant"
        onchange="actualizar_total()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" class="resul"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="PARLANTE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="80" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" required class="cant_actual cant"
         onchange="actualizar_total()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" class="resul"></td>
    </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
 <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>

<br>
<label>Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a </label>
<input type="hidden" value="12" id="cant_vm">
```

Comment: Como te había dicho en otra respuesta (de hecho me intriga que hasta tenga los mismos errores de tipeo), lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta. La respuesta será de utilidad solamente si explicas qué cambios has hecho y por qué. Recuerda siempre que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código.